# Recursive async function memory leaks

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, recursion, memory-management

I'm wondering if a recursive loop like this would case memory leaks in a long term

```
const loop = async (url: URL): Promise<void> => {
    
    await scrape(url)
    return await loop(url)
}

async function scrape(url: URL): Promise<void> {

    
    ...
    if (...)
       return await scrape(next_url)

}

function main() {
    await loop(...)
}

main()
```

The `loop` function is running indefinitely without stopping.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend moving the condition to the `loop` and using a `while` loop inside an asynchronous generator -

```js
async function* loop(url) {
    while (true) {
      let res = await scrape(url)
      if (...) return
      yield res
      url = nextUrl
    }
}
```

Your `scrape` function takes a `url` and returns a single result -

```
async function scrape(url) {
  ...
}
```

Finally your `main` function steps through the `loop` with `for await .. of` -

```js
async function main(initUrl) {
    const results = []
    for await (const res of loop(initUrl))
      results.push(res)
    return results
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

I might suggest renaming `scrape` to `scrape1`, as in *scrape one page*, and rename `loop` to `scrape`. An advantage to using an async generator is the caller can decide what to do with the pages as they come in. In the example above we `push` them to an array, but you could write to disk or any other operation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I was asking if a recursion like mine would cause memory leaks.

Comment: yes it definitely would because there's nothing to stop the `loop` after it starts.